# How to list all virtual machines created using qemu-system-x86_64?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am using `qemu-system-x86_64` to boot virtual machines on kvm running on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit desktop. I have a few VM's that are currently running. I want to get the list of all VM's booted using `qemu-system-x86_64` on this host machine, how do I get this list?

**Specifications:**

- qemu-system-x86_64 version 1.0
- linux 3.2.0-60-generic

**P.S.:** Just as a side note, I am aware of `virsh -c qemu:///system list` which would list all VMs booted using virsh. However, this does not seem to give the list of VMs booted using `qemu-system-x86_64`, it would be great if virsh command could list the VMs booted using `qemu-system-x86_64`.

Comment: +1 for the question.. Now me too want to get the answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each VM started with qemu-system-x86_64 corresponds to a process on the host machine. This means that a list of qemu-system-x86_64 processes corresponds to the list of VMs that are currently running on the host.

```
ps -ef | grep qemu-system-x86_64
```

This will list all the qemu-system-x86_64 processes, their pids and the parameters used to start the VM.

Comment: +1 for a good method, would appreciate a script that would help distinguish two virtual machines booted using `qemu-system-x86_64` (may have the same name).

Comment: If both VMs use the same image and you don't want to distinguish them by pid, you could assign a different MAC address for each VM. This depends off course also on your network settings, if this is an option:
-net nic,macaddr=<MACADDR>
Off course, this does not solve the problem for already existing VMs.

Comment: Thanks. Noting the process might not be named `qemu-system-x86_64`. In my case it is `qemu-kvm`.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a solution for some more advanced nice view (see source below):**

*This one shows all wemu-systems, not only the x86_64 ones.*

```
Cutton Eye@QEMU:~$ ps -ef | awk -e '/qemu/ && !/awk/' | sed -e 's/[^/]*//' -e 's/ -/\n\t-/g'

/18   00:00:17 qemu-system-x86_64
  -enable-kvm
  -hda MyDrive.img
  -m 1G
  -…
```

[Sean Swehla has created this awesome regex](https://gist.github.com/kitschysynq/867caebec581cee4c44c764b4dd2bde7)

Comment: What is the `-e` option for `awk`? I have to remove it to make the command work.

Comment: `awk` is a need tool for advanced scripting in command line. -e / --source is the actual script to be executed followed by the actual string. For your convenience don't hesitate to run `man awk` for retrieving the answer to your command line options.